# Limit the number of elements in the List using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a fiddle at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4YvaP/)

HTML

```
<ul class="lia-list-standard" id="list_2">
    <li class="label even-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/new" id="link_418" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">New<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">1</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label odd-row">            <a href="/10031/label-name/Rohan" id="link_419" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Rohan<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">1</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label even-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/Rahul" id="link_420" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Rahul<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">1</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label odd-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/Preet" id="link_421" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Preet<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">1</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label even-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/Singh" id="link_422" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Singh<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">1</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label odd-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/Random" id="link_423" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Random<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">2</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
    <li class="label even-row">            <a href="10031/label-name/Member" id="link_424" class="label-link lia-link-navigation">Member<wbr></wbr></a>
        <span class="label-count">2</span><span> Threads</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){

    $('.label-count').each(function() {
        $(this).after($('<span>').text(" Threads"));
    });

    $('.label-count').text(function(_, text) {
        return text.replace(/\ ( | \) / g, '');
    });
    }
});
```

My requirement is that out of the list, I need to show only 4 elements and hide the remaining, and show a link "show more", when some one clicks on "show more", the entire list should be visible and "show more" link should become "show less" and vice versa.

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle is great help, but you should put also your code inside the question for reference.

Comment: -5 votes for what?  It is always good to mention the reason of downvoting.

Comment: Every one is busy down voting this post, any one out there to actually reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4YvaP/33/

Easiest approach is :
1. Add 'Show More' and 'Show less' div.
2. Bind the event handlers on these divs.
3. Show/Hide appropriate div depending upon the list size.

Excerpt from jsfiddle:

```
$('.show-more').on('click', function(){
       $('.lia-list-standard li:gt(3)').show();
       $('.show-less').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.show-more').addClass('hidden');
    });

    $('.show-less').on('click', function(){
       $('.lia-list-standard li:gt(3)').hide();
       $('.show-more').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.show-less').addClass('hidden');
    });

    //Show only four items
    if ( $('.lia-list-standard li').length > 4 ) {
        /*$('.lia-list-standard li:gt(3)').hide();
        $('.show-more').removeClass('hidden');
        */

            $('.show-less').click();
    }
```

Comment: @RakeshJuyal Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for. I have one problem though.. I have about 10 lists using the same class and I would like to use the same thing as above, but working with ALL lists. Now it counts every list item of all classes together and thus shows or hides everything from the other lists as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave your other JS implementation up to you, but for the functionality you specified, you could do it by adding something like this

```
<button id="hide-list-btn" style="display:none">Show More</button>

<style>
.hidden-list-item {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var show_limit = 4;
    $('.lia-list-standard li').each(function(){
        if ($(this).index() >= show_limit) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-list-item');
            $('#hide-list-btn').show();
        }
    });

    $('#hide-list-btn').click(function(){
        $('.hidden-list-item').toggle();
        $('#hide-list-btn').text($('#hide-list-btn').text() == 'Show More' ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More')
    });
});
</script>
```

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/4YvaP/29/

Answer (score 0):

Try this links may this useful for you

[More or less Jquery](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/)

[Jquery more](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text)